# To what extent can a country criminalize acts outside its territory?

Tags: international, indonesia, china, extraterritorial-jurisdiction

Indonesia prohibits pornography.

If someone creates porn in Indonesia, that's illegal.

What about if an Indonesian citizen creates porn somewhere else?

What about if a non-Indonesian is a porn star somewhere else and then becomes a tourist in Indonesia?

Another recent example is this

https://9gag.com/gag/a2WR2je

China criminalized criticizing the CCP government for all people in the world. Can they really do that? Are there other examples of such codes?

Comment: Under the [Sexual Offences Act 2003](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/42/part/1/crossheading/offences-outside-the-united-kingdom) people who are UK citizens or residents, or who are neither, can be prosecuted in the UK, for sexual offences committed outside the UK that would be against UK law if committed inside the UK.

Comment: So if someone have sex with a 17 years old girl in Indonesia, where it's legal, and then one day that guy is a tourist in UK, they went to jail?

Comment: @user4951 No. Firstly because the legal age of consent in the UK is 16. Secondly, you need to be a national or resident (although not necessarily at the time the act was committed).

Comment: I wonder if this should be another question. I know porn star can be a tourist in Indonesia legally. I  know no body can make porn in Indonesia legally. What about an Indonesian that makes porn outside Indonesia. Is it legal?

Answer (score 2):

To the extent that the country's constitution allows the legislature to make a law with extraterritorial scope.

(Of course other countries may or may not cooperate with the enforcement of that law.)

There might be as many examples of laws intended to have extraterritorial scope as there are countries.

A non-exhaustive list in UK law:

- [the Money Laundering, Terrorist Financing and Transfer of Funds (Information on the Payer) Regulations 2017](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2017/692/contents/made), which gave effect in UK law to [the European Union's Fourth Money Laundering Directive](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32015L0849).
- [sections 1, 6, 7 of the Bribery Act 2010](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/23/contents)
- [Offences outside the United Kingdom, s72 Sexual Offences Act 2003](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/42/part/1/crossheading/offences-outside-the-united-kingdom)
- [sections 327 to 329 of the Proceeds of Crime Act 2002](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2002/29/section/327) and [civil recovery orders under part 5](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2002/29/part/5)
- [sections 63A to 63E, Extra-territorial jurisdiction for other terrorist offences etc, Terrorism Act 2000](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/11/part/VI/crossheading/extraterritorial-jurisdiction-for-other-terrorist-offences-etc)

Comment: @NateEldredge I agree with your first proposition. The second, however, seems addressed only to those cases where one country needs another country's cooperation as, for example, in requesting extradition. In other cases, any country may enforce whatever laws it might make regarding overseas conduct against anyone found within the country's territory (overseas money laundering comes to mind). See more here: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/is-the-illegality-of-an-action-constrained-to-a-country

Comment: @NateEldredge I agree with you. However, I wanted to avoid a debate about whether something is criminalised if the law cannot be enforced. Happy to be more explicit.